# Find data between two dates

Tags: powershell, datetime

i am developing a GUI where need to find data between two dates from a text file.

file contains data like below

```
timestamp;_tmp_MIN;_tmp_MAX;_tmp_AVERAGE
1598613120;8;8;8
1598613180;8;8;8
1598613240;8;8;8
1598613300;8;8;8
1598613360;8;8;8
1598613420;8;8;8
1598613480;8;8;8
1598613540;8;8;8
1598613600;8;8;8
1598613660;8;8;8
1598613720;8;8;8
1598613780;8;8;8
```

The date i am getting in below format from the GUI( To and From date )

```
Sunday, August 30, 2020 12:31:00 PM
```

i will convert the GUI date to epoch time.

Please need some idea how to go ahead.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: PLEASE, read the Tour page for this site. it will explain the rules you have violated ... and how to fix your Question. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a `[datetime]` instance to a unix timestamp by calculating the number of seconds since the epoch start (Jan 1st 1970):

```
function ConvertTo-UnixTime
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [datetime]$DateTime
  )

  begin {
    # Create epoch offset (Jan 1st 1970 at midnight, UTC)
    $unixEpoch = (Get-Date '1970-01-01T00:00:00z').ToUniversalTime()
  }

  process {
    # Convert input date to UTC, then calculate difference in seconds
    return [int][Math]::Floor(($DateTime.ToUniversalTime() - $unixEpoch).TotalSeconds)
  }
}

# Now we can easily convert from [datetime] to unix timestamp
$sampleDate = Get-Date 'Sunday, August 30, 2020 12:31:00 PM'
$sampleTimestamp = $sampleDate |ConvertTo-UnixTime
```

Now you can use it to filter against your data:

```
$startTimestamp,$endTimestamp = $startDateTime,$endDateTime |ConvertTo-UnixTime

Import-Csv .\path\to\file -Delimiter ';' |Where-Object { $startTimestamp -lt $_.timestamp -and $endTimestamp -gt $_.timestamp }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. just the kid i was looking for.